# How can I create an unit test to see the title of my page?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I've created a Unit Test Project inside my ASP.NET Core app, but I keep getting the error that it threw an exception.

This is my Index.html.cs

```
`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Presentation_app.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public string Title { get; private set; }

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
            Title = ViewData["Title"]?.ToString() ?? "";
        }
    }}
```

This is my Index.cshtml file

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

And this is my unit test I'm trying to use

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Presentation_app.Pages;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void UnitTestProject()
        {
            // Arrange
            var logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger<IndexModel>();
            var pageModel = new IndexModel(logger);

            // Act
            pageModel.OnGet();
            string title = pageModel.Title;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(title);
            Assert.AreEqual("Home page", title);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing it shows is this:
[image]

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a Unit Test Project inside my ASP.NET Core app, but I
> keep getting the error that it threw an exception.

Actually, you are getting null reference exception while initilizing value  on `ViewData["Title"]` it's because, ViewData value usually passed by the framework  at runtime. But within your scenario two projects are isolated thus, unit test would not happen automatically.

Therefore, You would need to initialize the instance of view data and the page model and thn need to pass viewdata instance and metadata within your TestMethod in Arrange area.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can do that:

**Project Reference:**

Include main project reference in unit test project as following:

[image]

**Unit Test Method:**

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void UnitTestProject()
        {

            // Arrange
            var logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger<IndexModel>();

            var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
            //Creating View data instance
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, new ModelStateDictionary());
            var pageModel = new IndexModel(logger)
            {
                PageContext = new PageContext
                {
                    ViewData = viewData
                },
                MetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider,
            };

            // Act
            pageModel.OnGet();
            string title = pageModel.Title!;

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(title);
            Assert.AreEqual("Home page", title);
        }
```

[image]

**Debug Test:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Razor page unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#unit-tests-of-the-page-model-methods) you could [check our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/razor-pages-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#unit-tests-of-the-page-model-methods)

Comment: The code is still not working. I have an errors regarding ViewDataDictionary and in index.html.cs it says 2 references or one reference, but none of them are passing the test.

Comment: The implementation is very straightforward, thus, have you placed the code accordingly? Does, your unit test project included main project reference? In addition, could you please include your lastest code within your question, so that it can be investigated exactly.